# Firestore TypeError: collection().where() is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to filter my docs in firebase firestore by checking if a doc 'users' array contains the user's email address. The 'chat' collection contains docs with ids: 'user@email.com:friend@email.com' and a doc contains messages and users stored in array.

I would like to list chats for the current user.
[image: The image shows one chat conversation in firestore]

The problem is that every time I would like to use the where() clause I get to following error:

**TypeError: firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.firestore(...).collection(...).where(...).onSnapshot(...).catch is not a function**

This is my code:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("chats").where("users", "array-contains", currentUser.email)
            .onSnapshot(async res => {
                setChats(res.docs)
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
            });
```

Comment: Did you import firebase from 'firebase' ?

Answer (score 1):

After read the ["onSnapshot" method reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#onsnapshot) I understood it does not return anything. The method signature has a `void` return. You may have to pass the callback you want to be called as parameter of the `onSnapshot` method.

Actually you have an exemple in the Firestore documentation at the [Handle listen errors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#handle_listen_errors) section.

Bellow the snippet of code from the documentation:

```js
db.collection("cities")
  .onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
    // Handle changes
  }, function(error) {
    // Handle errors
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue.I just not imported "where" method,couse when you click CTRL+space it is not showing for imports,and automatically it is not imports,I just written it by my hand.and it`s worked..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).